# Prove that $\rho(A+B)\le\rho(A)+\rho(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ commute, where $\rho$ is the spectral radius

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space. $A$ and $B$ are linear bounded operators on $X$, $\rho$ is the spectral radius. If $AB = BA$, show that $\rho(A+B) \leq \rho(A)+\rho(B)$.

Firstly I tried to use the formula $\rho(T) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \|T^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ if $T$ is a linear bounded operator. And if $AB = BA$,we have $(A+B)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n C_n^k A^k B^{n-k}$. So
$$\|(A+B)^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n C_n^k \|A^k\| \|B^{n-k}\|$$
Then I tried to prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{k=0}^n C_n^k \|A^k\| \|B^{n-k}\|)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \rho(A) + \rho(B)$, but failed.

Any kind of help is appreciated and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Math, the fact that $A$ and $B$ commute does not imply that they are normal.

Comment: You can find some elementary solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3341898/144766 Alternatively, you can use the Gelfand transform.

Comment: @ mechanodroid Thanks! It really helped me a lot.